# How to render DOMPDF within a page

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to figure out how best to render a PDF generated through the [DOMPDF wrapper](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) in my Laravel project. I'm able to generate the PDF in its own window via a route like this

```
//routes.php
Route::post('/contract', 'PDFController@contract');

...

//PDFController.php
public function contract()
{
    $signature = Input::get('signature_name');
    $dob = Input::get('signature_dob');
    $date = Input::get('signature_date');

    $data = array('name'=>$signature, 'dob'=>$dob, 'date'=>$date);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('contract', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('contract.pdf');
}
```

There's also a method to download the PDF. But what I'd like to do is render the PDF in its own section of a view. My first thought is that there's something like an `iframe` to do the rendering, but since it's using `$_POST` variables and Routes, I'm not sure if that complicates things. I'm not strongly attached to the DOMPDF either, so if there are other modules that work better, I'm definitely open to other options as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar recently.  What I did was set the src on the iframe so that a route will catch that and redirect to a method in my controller with the information you need.

So how that would work for you would be similar to...

```
Route::get('name/{name}/dob/{dob}/date/{date}', array('uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod', 'as' => 'pdf.streamer'));
```

I think your controller will probably need to output some special headers for that.  The method might like...

```
public function contract($name, $dob, $date)
{
    $data = array(
        'name'=>$name, 
        'dob'=>$dob, 
        'date'=>$date
    );

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('contract', $data);

    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($pdf));
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf));
    return $pdf->stream('contract.pdf');
}
```

If it doesn't work right, how I did it specifically is instead of returning something, i just had...

```
readfile('contract.pdf');
```